# How do I obtain user info (username / id) from Google API using Flask and rauth?

Tags: flask, google-api, rauth

Here is what I have got so far.

```
GOOGLE_AUTH_URI = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth'
GOOGLE_REVOKE_URI = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke'
GOOGLE_TOKEN_URI = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'
GOOGLE_BASE_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/'

redirect_uri = '127.0.0.1:5000/callback'    

google = OAuth2Service(
name='google',
client_id = GOOGLE_APP_ID,
client_secret = GOOGLE_APP_SECRET,
access_token_url=GOOGLE_TOKEN_URI,
authorize_url=GOOGLE_AUTH_URI,
base_url = GOOGLE_BASE_URL)


@app.route('/login/google')
def googleLogin():
params = {'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
          'access_type': 'offline',
          'response_type': 'code',
          'redirect_uri': redirect_uri}
return redirect(google.get_authorize_url(**params))

@app.route('/callback')
def callback():
    credentials = google.get_access_token(data = {'code':request.args['code'],
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'redirect_uri': redirect_uri},
        decoder = json.loads)

    return jsonify(refresh_token=credentials)
```

Now I want to store the user information after the user gives his/her consent in my database. How should I go about doing it?

Comment: What kind of data does `request.args` have in your callback method?

Comment: I am importing `request.args`  from the Flask library

Comment: I know what it is. I'm saying that it could have more than the `code` key you're fetching.

Comment: Can you please help me in understanding how should I go about write the callback process

Comment: The `request.args['code']` is coming to be `4/cMmBfo4BbNd87Yk6q0_JsoMmxmhLgretxViW7qKMUK8.4ja0d_BcDYMXcp7tdiljKKZByqhcmAI` with type unicode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the problem. The `get_access_token` function is flawed. [Follow this link for more information](https://github.com/litl/rauth/issues/110)